How can i show that the last equality in the text is true?
Suppose that $v$ is critical point of
$$
f(u)=\frac{1}{2} \int_D|\nabla u|^2-\frac{1}{p+1} \int_D|u|^{p+1}, \quad u \in H_{0, \text{rad}}^1(D),\quad D(r, d)=\left\{z \in R^N: r^2<|z|^2<(r+d)^2\right\},
$$
i.e.,
$$
\left\langle f^{\prime}(v), \varphi\right\rangle=0, \quad$$
$ \forall \varphi \in \left\{v \in H_0^1(D(r, d)): v(x, y)=u(|x|,|y|) \text {, for some } u\right\}
$
Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
& x=\left(x_1, x_2\right)=s \omega_1, \quad s>0, \quad \omega_1 \in S^1 \\
& y=\left(y_1, \ldots, y_{N-2}\right)=t \omega_{N-3}, \quad t>0, \quad \omega_{N-3} \in S^{N-3} ; \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
$\forall \varphi \in C_0^{\infty}(D)$, let
$$
\bar{\varphi}(x, y)=f_{\omega_{N-s} \in S^{N-s}} f_{\omega_1 \in S^1} \varphi\left(|x| \omega_1,|y| \omega_{N-3}\right) \, d \omega_1 \, d \omega_{N-3},
$$
where $f_{S^{N-s}}$ denotes the integral divided by the volume of $S^{N-3}$ and $f_{S^1}$ denotes the integral divided by the volume of $S^1$. . Let $\tilde{\varphi}=\varphi-\bar{\varphi}$.
How can I show
\begin{equation}
\int_D v \tilde{\varphi}=\int_D|v|^{p-1} v \tilde{\varphi}=\int_D \nabla v \, \nabla \bar{\varphi}=0\text{?}
\end{equation}
